# wordpress recent categories widget

Tags: wordpress

I have used the following code to display the recent categories `<?php wp_list_categories( 'title_li=<h3>' . __('Recent Categories') . '</h3>' ); ?>`. I need to exclude some categories from display. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using 'get_categories' instead. It's a bit more complicated, but a lot more flexible. You can exclude specific cats with this function by including a comma-separated list of categories in the args. See below:

```
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'exclude' => '1,4,9' <--- Add your cats to exclude here
);

$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' .   sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
}
```

Read more about get_categories at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories
?>